# Lightning Component: Loading $Resource, then action function, then $Resource

Tags: lightning-aura-components, static-resources, callback

I am working on a lightning component where I want to load resources then, an action function, then resources, then action function. I currently have the component set up like this:

```
<ltng:require styles="{!join(',', 
        $Resource.bootstrap3 + '/css/bootstrap.min.css', 
        $Resource.customCSS,
        $Resource.lightgallery + '/lightgallery/css/lightgallery.css',
        $Resource.SLDS100 + '/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system-vf.css')}"
      afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.loadSfEnv}"/>

<!-- 60 lines of html -->

<ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.myCustomAppBundle_js}"
    afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.loadCustomApp}"/>
```

The `c.loadSfEnv` has an apex callback in it that gets data needed in the `$Resource.myCustomAppBundle_js`, which loads code needed in the `c.loadCustomApp`. The `c.loadCustomApp` action function also has apex calls in it and so its javascript can't be added to the `$Resource.myCustomAppBundle_js`. Most of the time the way of doing it above works because because the `c.loadSfEnv` callback is finished before `$Resource.myCustomAppBundle_js` loads but occasionally it doesn't load it in time and the page breaks.

Is there a way to ensure that `$Resource.myCustomAppBundle_js` is loaded only after the callback in `c.loadSfEnv` has completed? I've tried things like this below but it doesn't work.

```
 <ltng:require scripts="{!join(',',
        c.loadSfEnv, 
        $Resource.formDisplayAppBundle_js)}"
    afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.loadForm}"/>
```

**Update:** An alternate solution would be to load the $Resource.formDisplayAppBundle_js in the callback of the c.loadSfEnv but I didn't know if that was possible.

Comment: why not have just one `ltng:require` and call `c.loadSfEnv` then call helper's  `loadCustomApp()` method?

Comment: I'm not sure if I exactly understand what you are suggesting here but the order of loading is what's important here. It needs to be the c.loadSfEnv method, then the $Resource, then the c.loadForm method in that order, once the call backs are done. Both those methods are in the js controller. Another option would be to load the static resource from the controller but I didn't think that was possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I figured this out, with a hint from [this blog post](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/03/reports-salesforc1-lightning-components-jquery-mobile.html). My `c.loadSfEnv` is now patterned like this with the static resource load and the contents `c.loadForm` added to it as part of its internal callback chain:

```
window.sfEnv = {};

let getInitInfo = cmp.get("c.getInitInfo");

getInitInfo.setCallback(this, function(response) {
    let state = response.getState()
    if (response.getState() === "SUCCESS") {
        let info = JSON.parse(response.getReturnValue());

        sfEnv.countryPicklists = info.countryPicklistsEnabled;
        sfEnv.namespace = info.namespace;
        cmp.set('v.namespace',info.namespace);

        //Then load App Static Resource so its methods can be used later
        var loadScript = document.createElement('script');
        loadScript.setAttribute('src', '/resource/myCustomAppBundle_js');
        document.head.appendChild(loadScript);

        //This was initially called in c.loadCustomApp
        let getMoreFromApex = cmp.get("c.getMoreFromApex");
        getMoreFromApex.setCallback(this, function(response){
            if (response.getState() === "SUCCESS") {
                let myData = JSON.parse(response.getReturnValue());
                window.methodCreatedInStaticRes(myData);
            }
        });

        $A.enqueueAction(getMoreFromApex);
    }
});

$A.enqueueAction(getInitInfo);
```

Then on the page I just have this at the bottom since the static resource app references a div in the component html:

```
<ltng:require scripts=""
    afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.loadSfEnv}"/>
```

Comment: why do you want to call `getMoreFromApex` again after sfEnv is set?

Comment: why not have `<ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.myCustomAppBundle_js}"
    afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.loadSfEnv}"/>`.So first loadSfEnv will be called followed by `getMoreFromApex()` method and finally `methodCreatedInStaticRes()`

Comment: I'm calling `c.getMoreFromApex` after the bundle because I need different things at different times in that order. The root issue is that I was trying to port a JQuery app designed for a VisualForce page into a Lightning Component while only re-writing a minimal amount of code and not loosing the VisualForce compatibility. The JQuery app has VisualForce Remoting throughout it that I had to bypass and replace with callbacks in the lightning component js controller. Were it greenfield, I would've put more code into the lightning js controller/helper to avoid this but that wasn't possible.

Comment: Ok I got your point.If the answer solves the problem, please mark it as accepted.